# Underline the implicit Textblock created in Silverlight for a ContentPresenter when Content is a string?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, contentpresenter

I am trying to create a template for a content control such as Button or HeaderedContentControl etc. where the text is underlined.

I just want to underline the text when `Content="This text is underlined"` is specified.

It must continue to work as normal if Content is another UIElement.

Most posts asking this same question are satisfied with modifying the template to only work for a string as content. Scott Gu has a good article about [styling buttons](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx) but doesn't address this issue.

The following sample will work if you actually pass in `Content` as an instance of type `TextBlock` but not as a string. Surely the visual tree has a TextBlock so it should style it. Perhaps this is a Sivlerlight limitation.

This example shows black text and big red text when I want it to display both as big red text.

```
    <navigation:Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="style123">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="72"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
    </Style>
</navigation:Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>        

    <!-- This doesn't work and shows black text -->
    <ContentPresenter Content="Small black text">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource style123}"/>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>

    <!-- This works and shows red text -->
    <ContentPresenter>
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="This is big red text"/>
        </ContentPresenter.Content>

        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource style123}"/>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: PS. I'm fine if the solution is something crazy like subclassing ContentPresenter and intercepting events or something like that. hmm i just realized perhaps that might work...

Comment: Crazy solutions are rarely needed in WPF - see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass whatever actual `ContentControl` (i.e. `Button`) you are using and override `OnContentChanged` in order to reset the `Content` property to an underlined `TextBlock` if the newContent is a string. In the case that the newContent is not a string it would perform in the usual way.

```csharp
public class UnderlineButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        if (newContent is string)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = newContent as string;
            textBlock.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
            this.Content = textBlock;
        }

        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
    }
}
```

It's kind of annoying to subclass just to accomplish this but it avoids messy style templates and subclassing `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: thanks! wouldn't this need to be an else condition for base.OCC()?

Comment: I don't think so, you are always going to want to notify the base control of the content change. In the case that the newContent is a string you are just "jumping in" and switching out the actual content first.

Comment: ahh thats right... this is OnContentChanged as opposed to OnContentChanging (which may not actually exit - I didnt check). looking like this solution is the best for Silverlight right now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, using a DataTemplate to custom-render `string` content (I've just set the background to red):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourData}" >
  <ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:String}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

EDIT: just as a note, you could pull this out into a `ContentControl` style rather than applying it inline each time, if you need better reusability...

Comment: i did try to get something like this working before but couldn't get it working with silverlight. i know this is WPF cos in silverlight we don't even have Background on a TextBlock! :-(